# NVD3 - Positioning of xAxis labels not working

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

I'm new to NVD3 and D3 in general. I've setup a graph and using an array to pass strings for the labels on the xAxis. Unfortunately they are not positioning properly.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/darcyvoutt/daw7s/

full screen (see issue easier): http://jsfiddle.net/darcyvoutt/daw7s/embedded/result/

Here is the code:

```
nv.addGraph(function() {
  var chart = nv.models.multiBarChart()    
    .color(["#24545F", "#428696", "#6DADBD", "#58CBE7"])
    .transitionDuration(10)
    .showControls(false)
    .groupSpacing(0.55) 
    .showLegend(true)    
    .stacked(true)    
    .delay(350)
    ;

  var tickMarks = ["YourPhone","Universe X3", "ePhone 74s", "NextUs", "Humanoid"];

  chart.xAxis      
      .tickValues(tickMarks)
      .axisLabel("Products")
      ;

  chart.yAxis
      .tickFormat(d3.format(',1f'))
      ;

  d3.select('#salesChart svg')
      .datum(exampleData())
      .call(chart)
      ;

  nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

  return chart;
});
```

For emphasis, the variable and passing is as follows:

```
  var tickMarks = ["YourPhone","Universe X3", "ePhone 74s", "NextUs", "Humanoid"];

  chart.xAxis      
      .tickValues(tickMarks)
      ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up figuring out the issue, I didn't need the `.tickValues` at all, if I simply changed my `x` value in the datum then it would work fine, here is the data structure.

```
function exampleData() {
  return [
    {
      "key": "Basic Planners",
      "values": [{"x": "YourPhone","y": 150}, 
                 {"x": "Universe X3","y": 300},
                 {"x": "ePhone 74s","y": 1500}, 
                 {"x": "NextUs","y": 50}, 
                 {"x": "Humanoid","y": 500
                }]
    }, {
      "key": "No-Namers",
      "values": [{"x": "YourPhone","y": 300}, 
                 {"x": "Universe X3","y": 250}, 
                 {"x": "ePhone 74s","y": 400}, 
                 {"x": "NextUs","y": 150}, 
                 {"x": "Humanoid","y": 900}]

    }, {
      "key": "Feature Followers",
      "values": [{"x": "YourPhone","y": 350}, 
                 {"x": "Universe X3","y": 900}, 
                 {"x": "ePhone 74s","y": 100}, 
                 {"x": "NextUs","y": 500}, 
                 {"x": "Humanoid","y": 250}]

    }, {
      "key": "Hipsters & Elites",
      "values": [{"x": "YourPhone","y": 200}, 
                 {"x": "Universe X3","y": 350}, 
                 {"x": "ePhone 74s","y": 50}, 
                 {"x": "NextUs","y": 800}, 
                 {"x": "Humanoid","y": 100}]

    }
  ]
}
```

Previous it looked more like:

```
"values": [{"x": 0","y": 150}, 
                 {"x": 1,"y": 300},
                 {"x": 2,"y": 1500}, 
                 {"x": 3,"y": 50}, 
                 {"x": 4,"y": 500
                }]
```

Answer (score 1):

Not a perfect solution but this may help http://jsfiddle.net/daw7s/3/ using tickFormat

```
  chart.xAxis
  .tickFormat(function(d){
        return tickMarks[d];
   })
  .axisLabel("Products")
  ;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, that definitely works as well, though after I ended up realizing that I could simply change the values in the datum, that's a cleaner solution in my mind as I can build a single array to pull from the db.

Comment: Yeah, I saw your post later. Glad you found the solution :)

Comment: I think we posted at the same time. I really appreciate it, this may still come in handy on a situation where the labels are static.

Comment: +1 For the solution. @dvoutt don't forget to accept your answer.

Comment: Thanks, have to wait till tomorrow won't let me yet. Lol